# Label flashing with timers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, timer

I'm trying to get a couple labels to flash on a button click. With the current code, the first click works properly, and each click afterwards only does half the amount of blinking it should (to white and back to black). Any ideas on how to improve/fix this? Here's my current code:

```
private int counter;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     //Labels start out black, then play a sequence
     //of changing to white and back to black twice
     lb1.BackColor = Color.White;
     lb2.BackColor = Color.White;

     counter = 0;
     timer.Interval = 300; 
     timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);
     timer.Enabled = true;
     timer.Start(); 
}

void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (counter ==2)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Enabled = false;
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (lb2.BackColor == Color.Black)
        {
            lb1.BackColor = Color.White;
            lb2.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            lb1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            lb2.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
        counter += 1;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an event handler to `Timer.Tick` on each button click.

Try moving the line `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);` out of `button1_Click_2` function.

when you call `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);` another handler will be added for `Tick` event. It causes multiple `TimerElapsed` to be fired when you click on the button and this cause the problem. By moving `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);` outside the `button1_Click_2` function you just assign `TimerElapsed` to event once.