# Stop Label from flickering on Timer.Tick

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am making an application that has a countdown.
The issue is, the Label is flickering when its Text is updated on a Timer Tick.

Note: I did find a *duplicate question*, however the issue remained after applying that fix. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127381/label-flashing-with-timers)

Thanks in advance

```
DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 21, 13, 0, 0);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Interval = 500;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    countDown.Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'");
    t.Start();
}

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
    countDown.Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds'");
}
```

Comment: add the link of your dupe to your question.

Comment: There should be no problems with your code. Do you do some heavy calculations while the timer is ticking?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy currently nothing else is going on within the application, just the time. However, I do have a background image on the form items, not sure if thats causing part of the issue.

Comment: Try setting `Form.DoubleBuffered = true`

Comment: @Jimi What an amazing fix! Thank you so much. Please submit as an answer and I will mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you said in the comments, an Image is assigned to your `Form.BackGroundImage`, updating the UI can cause flickering. This is quite normal.
To eliminate (or considerably reduce) the flickering, activate the [Double Buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered?view=netframework-4.7.2) feature of the Form:

```
Form.DoubleBuffered = true
```

From the Docs:

> Buffered graphics can reduce or eliminate flicker that is caused by
>   progressive redrawing of parts of a displayed surface. Buffered
>   graphics require that the updated graphics data is first written to a
>   buffer. The data in the graphics buffer is then quickly written to
>   displayed surface memory. The relatively quick switch of the displayed
>   graphics memory typically reduces the flicker that can otherwise
>   occur.

Some interesting documents on the subject:

[Double Buffered Graphics (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/double-buffered-graphics)
[How to: Reduce Graphics Flicker with Double Buffering for Forms and Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls)

If the activation of Double Buffering only partially eliminates the flickering, try to modify some bit flags of the class using the [SetStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) method, enabling these [ControlStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) features. In the Form constructor:
(also a valid method for other controls, expecially the Panel class)

```
public Form1()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
             ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
             ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    this.UpdateStyles();
}
```